# Django: How to parse slug from url typed in address bar?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to simulate Google's behavior where the user types something on the address bar of the browser and the Django server checks for any exact matches in the database.  If so, a detailview of the object is rendered.  If not an exact match, then a list of matches on substrings are rendered with ListView.

This behavior works fine when the user types into a search form.  For instance, when the user just types the letter '**j**' in the search form and hits submit, the Django server matches on 3 objects in the data base 'D**j**ango, **J**ava, node.**j**s' and renders this list through ListView.  If there is an exact match, say the user typed '**java**', then the Django server renders details about the object 'java' in a Detail view.

However, I could not figure out how to derive the same behavior when applied to what the user types on the address bar of the browser.  If the user happens to type just the exact spelling of an item in the db, the details of the item is rendered, otherwise we get a 404 error.

The relevant segments of the html form, urls.py, and views.py are displayed below

```
   <form method="GET" action="{% url 'searchwiki' %}">
      <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
   </form>
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.EntryListView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path("entries/",views.EntryListView.as_view(),name='entries'),
    path("entry/<int:pk>",views.EntryDetailView.as_view(),name="entry_detail"),
    path("<int:pk>", views.EntryDetailView.as_view(), name="path_entry-detail"),
    # path("<slug:subject>",views.get_obj_orlist),
    path("<slug:subject>",views.EntryDetailView.as_view()),
    path("random/",views.randompage,name="randompage"),
    path("searchwiki/",views.searchwiki,name="searchwiki"),
]
```

views.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .models import Entry
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

def searchwiki(request):
    searchtoken = request.GET.get('q')
    try:
        entry = Entry.objects.get(subject=searchtoken)
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        entries = Entry.objects.filter(subject__icontains=searchtoken)
        print("Inside exception code.  qset size is ",len(entries))
        return render(request, 'wikiencyc/searchencyc.html','entries':entries,'searchtoken':searchtoken})
    return redirect(entry)

def get_obj_orlist(request):
    model = Entry
    slug_field = 'subject'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'subject'

    # below is the solution if it works
    slug = kwargs.get(slug_url_kwarg)
    try:
        entry = Entry.objects.get(subject=slug)
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        entries = Entry.objects.filter(subject__icontains=slug)
        return render(request, 'wikiencyc/searchencyc.html', {'entries':entries,'searchtoken':slug} )
    return redirect(entry)

class EntryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entry
    slug_field = 'subject'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'subject'
```

The "searchwiki/" path in urls.py and the searchwiki(request) function in views.py work perfectly together for said functionality in response to search form.

As for parsing the slug from the address bar, the EntryDetailView(generic.DetailView) does a perfect job for an exact match of the parsed slug in the database, but responds with a 404 exception to the screen instead of a list of substring matches.

My attempt at replicating the searchwiki function for the addressbar is the function get_obj_orlist(request).  It fails because I could not figure out how to get the slug from the address bar and urlconf to said function.  It is probably something very simple but after 2 days of searching through the Django server code and docs I am saying AARRGG!!! when I see args and kwargs.  Any help is deeply appreciated.  I am still struggling with regular expressions, so I would appreciate it if these can be avoided in the solution presentation.

Comment: Please do format your code properly

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I apologize.  It was the first time that I posted code on the site.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 when it doesn't exist this implies that `wikiencyc/searchencyc.html`doesn't exist ... What does your debug log say it's looking for? Side comment: I usually avoid rendering templates directly like this and do it via a `reverse` url lookup and a view - it's easier to maintain, but essentially a personal choice.

Comment: @urbanespaceman The said template html file does indeed exist.  I narrowed the problem to how to access the parsed slug information from what the user types in the address bar for the url.  If the user types http://127.0.0.1:8000/wikiencyc/java , the generic DetailView code can parse the 'java' part at the end and assign it as a slug to the 'subject' key word in the view class code.  If the user just types 'j' at the end for the slug it returns a 404 error because there is no exact match in the db.  The knowledge I am lacking is how the slug is parsed and passed to the vıew as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  As I had expected, it was a very trivial overlook.  Just including subject as a parameter into the function allowed its use in the Entry model for querying purposes.  The working function is depicted below.

```
def get_obj_orlist(request, subject):
model = Entry
try:
    entry = Entry.objects.get(subject=subject)
except Entry.DoesNotExist:
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(subject__icontains=subject)
    return render(request, 'wikiencyc/searchencyc.html', {'entries':entries,'searchtoken':subject} )
return redirect(entry)
```